# Javascript form manipulation in woocommerce custom search form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, woocommerce

I am storing some values in a hidden field in the form of a custom woocommerce category page. After storing when i print the values in console or alert them, they display fine but when the form is submitted the values don't carry forward.
I have tried storing the values via jQuery and DOM. Value are stored fine using both, when i print the values of form field in the console. I can see them

Comment: can you show us what you have in the network console of your web browser when you are doing the form request ?

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Problem is that value i set in the fields are linked to fields in value attribute before form is submit and when i print post array the value are not carried to php. Neither through get nor post method of form

Comment: There is the screenshots of my form fields http://prntscr.com/ebztp0

Comment: This is link of screenshots of form and js script which binds map longitude and latitude to the form field "#pickuplat1" and "#pickuplong1". Below are links of all screenshots in sequence
http://prnt.sc/ebzwim
http://prnt.sc/ebzwt9
http://prnt.sc/ebzy3t
http://prnt.sc/ebzyy1

pickuplat1 and pickuplong1 variables in last screenshot give hard coded values in post array print but not the js script assigned values. But before form submit value changes i saw in console but not carries to php

Comment: @Kornflexx can you please see the links ?